# error: unknown filesystem. grub resuce>

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit with a live CD and asked it to wipe Windows. I had a dual boot before and did not really like Windows anyway. Now when I boot it without the CD I get this error message:

```
error: unknown filesystem. 
grub resuce>
```

I am not sure what to do with this error message. I have saved all my data from all 4 hard drives in the desktop. I am not sure which one Ubuntu is on, as I am totally new to this. I have tried to fix this for a month and have been unsuccessful. I am happy to reformat anything if this is going to help me, although I would not know how to do that either. Can anyone out there help? Please treat me like a real beginner as far as the steps and terminology are concerned. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the second option in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If the problem still persist, then post the contents of your boot-repair log in your question.

Comment: Avinash Raj. You have fixed my 1 year long problem!!!!!!! so many have tried now my desktop computer starts Ubuntu without the live disc.  You are my hero! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

### Reformatting and re-installing Ubuntu

You wanted it, and i will try my best to make you understand the progress on how to fix this. Lets assume that something went wrong during the installation of the OS. It could be that your pc was restarted before it could finish the installation, or the GRUB boot loader wasn't properly installed. Now, i am going to show you how to reformat the harddrive, which from my view, seem to be the easiest and best solution to your problem.

1. Make sure to put in your LiveCD, and start up the Ubuntu Installation again. When you come to the step where it asks you to wipe any old installations on your system, you should choose **"Something Else"**

   [image: Select Something Else]
2. When you have, it will appear a new window (image below). You will have one or more partition the list. *A partition is in many ways a virtual hard-drive, but is physically just space divided into different sections on your harddrive.* However, this step isn't that hard. Select the hard-drive using **"ext3"** or **"ext4"** located under **type** and click **delete**. *(Be sure you are doing changes on your hard-drive and that you don't have any other devices like memory sticks inserted while you do this)*

[image: The partition table]

---

3. Now you have deleted that file-system from your hard-drive. on this step, you must select the partition you just deleted the file system from, and click **add**.
4. A new window pops up. Make sure `primary` is selected. From the menu in the "Use as", select `EXT4 Journaling File System`.
   The Size you have as default, should be subtracted with 1024. *(if you have 2048 as default, you should enter a value like this: 2048-1024 = 1024)* --> this will be used as Swap. Now, click OK.

Now you have an empty partition, a small one. Select that small one, and click `add`. Leave the Partition size as it is here, and from the list on `Use As:` you simply select **Swap** and click ok.

---

Once you are happy with the changes you have made, click “Install now” and you are good to go. Hopefully this installation will work.

Good luck, got questions --> just ask :)

Comment: Thanks does this also work with 5 internal Hard drives?  Will the program know which one to reformat?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. That list of hard-drives will be updated and all drives will be shown. The difficult part is to know which one of them to use, if you haven't named them properly or the sizes of them are equal.